# embedding silverlight application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a ASP.Net application with charts . The charts are drawn with the data from DB. 
I want to make the charts more interactive like in silver light. how do i proceed??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're new to Silverlight development so this may end up being a pretty daunting task for you.

Take look at the following video tutorial: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/charting-controls/silverlight-toolkit-column-chart.  In the video, Jesse Liberty walks through the creation of a Silverlight chart.
Also, make sure to download Microsoft's [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) to get started.